# Mocha/Chai: how to test Mongoose Schema Arrays of objects

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

currently saving an Array type with Mongoose, I don't pass the test

```
let resourcePublic = {
  name: 'RS123',
  description: 'RS123Description',
  owner: newUser.id,
  permissions: [{ level: 'group', level_id: newGroup.id, canWrite: true }],
  private: false
};

it('should create a new public resource', (done) => {
  request(app)
    .post('/api/v1/resources')
    .send(resourcePublic)
    .expect(httpStatus.OK)
    .then((res) => {
      ...
      expect(res.body.permissions).to.have.same.members(resourcePublic.permissions);
      ...
      resourcePublic = res.body;
      done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

the ACTUAL Array has the object_id field inserted after the document being saved.. which the expected does not have

```
  ACTUAL
  res.body.permissions:  [ 
      { level: 'group',
      level_id: '58f4b9c7110e5e7abd4f0425',
      _id: '58f4b9cb110e5e7abd4f042d',
      canWrite: true } 
  ]
  EXPECTED
  resourcePublic.permissions:  [
  { level: 'group',
      level_id: '58f4b9c7110e5e7abd4f0425',
      canWrite: true }
  ]
```

Is there any way to pass the test ?
thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you need to include a `.deep` because you're comparing arrays-of-objects (if you don't include `.deep`, Chai will just compare the two objects using `===` which will never be true).

But even so, I don't think you can get Chai to ignore that extra `_id`. Instead, I would probably split the test in two parts: first check if the items in `res.body.permissions` have an `_id` property, then remove it and finally perform a deep comparison against `resourcePublic`.

So:

```
res.body.permissions.permissions.forEach(item => {
  expect(item).to.have.property('_id');
  delete item._id;
});
expect(res.body.permissions).to.deep.have.same.members(resourcePublic.permissions);
```

As an aside, since you're using promise-based code, I would suggest taking advantage of Mocha's [built-in promise support](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises). Your tests will require (a bit) less code, and it may help you prevent certain issues when mixing callbacks and promises:

```
it('should create a new public resource', () => {
  return request(app)
    .post('/api/v1/resources')
    .send(resourcePublic)
    .expect(httpStatus.OK)
    .then((res) => {
      ...
      // assertions here
      ...
    });
});
```